mount.cifs error(78): Remote address changed
Setup:
Windows fileserver (cluster with 2 nodes actually) & a RHEL 8 host residing in the same Active Directory domain, multiple locations on the fileserver mounted using mount.cifs.
Our problem occurs nondeterministically when the fileserver cluster experiences a failover from one node to the other. Mostly the RHEL mounts work as expected, but in some rare cases we all cifs mounts from the same fileserver fail:
[root@foo ~]# mount /mnt/bar
mount error(78): Remote address changed
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

This failed mount attempts are also present in /var/log/messages:
kernel: CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -78

Not sure what exactly causes this error or how to properly fix it.
Since we encounter this problem rarely, it may take a fair amount of time to add further details to the question.

Not sure what causes the error, but we have a workaround for it.
As I stated above, when I try to umount and the mount the failing paths one at a time, we keep getting the same "remote address changed" errors.
But when I umount all of the affected paths, something changes and after that, mounting them again will work as expected.
